# How can I connect to a MySQL database into Apache Spark using SparkR?

Tags: mysql, r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am working on Spark 2.0 and SparkR libs. I want to get a sample code on how can I do following things in SparkR?

Connect to a MySQL or any other SQL database using SparkR.

Write SQL queries like SELECT , UPDATE etc. to modify a table in that database.

I know to do it using R. However I would need some help to use Spark Sessions or SparkSQL context. I am using R Studio for the development.

Moreover, how do we submit this R code as Spark Batch to run continuously at a regular intervals?

Comment: The question that springs to mind is, why do you want to do this?  Spark is a distributed processing environment for handling huge data sets that are best processed using parallel processing using a cluster of computers.  In contrast, you have a data set that exists in a single file on a single MySQL database, which by definition exists on a single computer.  An answer can be crafted on how to do this, but it seems grossly inefficient to do it on Spark instead of just doing it using on the local computer that contains the MySQL database using say Python.

Comment: thanks for your answer.But I am just experimenting stuff and Its not real life implementation.I build the dummy data using Mysql.I want to follow the steps for using SparkR considering mysql workbench is the representation of different data sources.I would appreciate if you can help me for the correct code and I am using Spark 2.0.0.

Comment: Understood @SCB, I was discouraged by our DBAs from making any SQL connections from Spark using jdbc, as each core in the cluster will make a separate connection to the database and start downloading data simultaneously.  The recommended method is to export the data to file (in HDFS if you are using Spark on Hadoop) and import into a DataFrame from file using: `df <- read.df(csvPath, "csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "NA")`

Answer (score 0):

```
jdbcurl <- "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.x.x:xxxx/database"

data <- read.jdbc(jdbcurl, "tablename", user = "user", password = "password" )
```

Comment: thanks sahil.Can you please let me know is it for sparkR and I am using Spark 2.0.0

Comment: Hi After running this code Iam getting below error.16/08/22 10:18:13 ERROR RBackendHandler: jdbc on 5 failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
  java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Comment: yup its for SparkR. Now you have to move the jdbc jar file into lib.

Comment: I am trying to work on sparkR environment where spark version is 2.0.0.

Comment: please let me know how to move forward

Comment: I am very much new on Spark,never used before.

Comment: first download the required jar then move it.  **spark-client/external/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar** . This is my jar classpath of spark